# Cuda thread Indexing To calculate threadIdx and ThreadIdy

Tags: cuda

I have a very basic doubt suppose I have a 2D grid and 2D blocks and I want to calculate the threadIdx and threadIdy for a particular thread in a block.
I know `blockId = blockIdx.y*gridDim.x*gridDim.y  + blockIdx.x`
and so `threadIdx=threadIdx.x`
and `threadIdy=blockId*blockDim.x*blockDim.y+threadIdx.y*blockDim.x`
Is this correct?
Actually I want to do matrix multiplication using 2D grid and 2D block that is why I need the x index and y index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a 2D grid of 2D threadblocks, where you want a unique (x,y) index combination for each thread, it's pretty simple:

```
int idx = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
int idy = threadIdx.y+blockDim.y*blockIdx.y;
```

Comment: how do I get a unique linear index for every thread in an arbitrary grid configuration?

Comment: a generic globally unique index could be: `size_t id = (threadIdx.z+blockDim.z*blockIdx.z)*(gridDim.x*blockDim.x*gridDim.y*blockDim.y)+(threadIdx.y+blockDim.y*blockIDx.y)*(gridDim.x*blockDim.x)+(threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x);`  This is the z-index times the size of the x-y slice, plus the y-index times the size of a row in x, plus the x-index.